# MySql 5.7.18 error in Group by clause with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am on Ubuntu Server 16.xx with MySql version 5.7.18,

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    w.sno,
    CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
       (SELECT 
          bch_lbl 
        FROM
          list_benches 
        WHERE sno = w.lb_sno),
          ' => ',
          CASE
            WHEN w.bench_cat_sno = 0 
            THEN 'All Categories' 
          ELSE 
            (SELECT 
               cat_name 
            FROM
               case_categories 
            WHERE sno = w.bench_cat_sno) 
         END,
          ' [From ',
            b.date_from,
          ' To ',
          b.date_to,
           '] '
         ),
     CASE
        WHEN b.is_active = 1 
     THEN 'Active' 
     ELSE 'Expired' 
    END
      ) AS benchLbl,
        w.is_active,
        b.j_sno 
  FROM
      working_benches w,
      bench_judges b 
  WHERE w.sno = b.b_sno 
  GROUP BY w.sno 
  ORDER BY b.is_active DESC ;
```

after execution, this query return the following error:

```
Error Code: 1055
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains 
nonaggregated column 'phc_caseflow.b.date_from' which is not functionally 
dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

The only thing i have understood is "**sql_mode=only_full_group_by**" which become cause of the above error.

Can anybody suggest me how to change the above query to fit into and fix the problem - need to edit my query only not the sql_mode:

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review all the Logs file and google the problem, i find that this is a "**BIG**" update in MySql Version minor version i.e **v 5.7.18**. So, the solution i have find was to do the following shortcut:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
Add this to the end of the file

[mysqld]  
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

And my queries running very good on server, i mean on my production server...

Answer (score -1):

Right out of the gate the problem I see with your query is that you are formatting the results within the SQL statement rather than in your application.

The addition of things like " =>" and "From [", "Active", "Expired" give that away. This type of formatting should be done in your application, not in your SQL.

My suggestion would be to rework the query, remove the use of CONCAT (for sure) and CASE (if possible) and make the query ONLY return the raw data you are after.

Once you have the query working and returning the raw data, format it as necessary in your application code. If this is not possible, I suspect you will battle with this query for quite a while longer.

Comment: i have already run the same query on my developer machine where the "sql_mode" is not the "only full group by", its working fine, furthermore, i have kept the case and concat in the query just because i have put it in the procedure and calling the same times and again...to populate the dropdown list from multiple table.

Comment: I here you. Thing is, it looks like a classic case of "works on my machine". While that's true, it isn't working in production which is where it matters. It seems your options might be limited.